# no matching constructor for initialization of 'No_default[]'

Tags: c++, templates, vector, initialization

I'm a beginner and I'm working through Stroustrup's book - Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd edition).

In chapter 19.3.7 Generalizing vector, I'm stuck at the following:

We created our own vector class over the past chapters.
To generalize, templates are used.
With templates, default types are introduced that need to be passed into the class as template parameters. For instance to resize the vector:

`template<typename T> void vector<T>::resize(int newsize, T def = T());`

To test that this works this struct is created without a default value:

```
struct No_default {
  No_default(int); // only constructor for No_default
  // ...
};
```

Then in the book it is initialized as follows:

```
vector<No_default> v3;
v3.resize(100, No_default(2));
```

But I get this error:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'No_default[]'
    T* p = new T[newalloc];
```

How would I write this struct, so that it can be initialized as shown above?

And here is the custom vector class:

```
template<typename T> 
class vector {
/*
  invariant:
  if 0 <= sz, elem[n] is element n
  sz <= space
  if sz < space, there is space for (space-sz) doubles after elem[sz-1]
*/
  int sz; 
  T* elem; 
  int space;
public:
  vector():sz{0}, elem{nullptr}, space{0} { }; 
  explicit vector(int s); 
  vector(std::initializer_list<T>lst);

  vector(const vector& v);
  vector& operator=(const vector& v); 

  vector(vector&& v); 
  vector& operator=(vector&& v); 

  T& operator[](int n); 
  const T& operator[](int n) const;

  ~vector()
  {
    delete[] elem;
  }

  int size() const { return sz; }
  int capacity() const { return space; } 

  void resize(int newsize, T def = T()); 
  void push_back(const T& d); 
  void reserve(int newalloc);

};

template<typename T> vector<T>::vector(int s)
  :sz{s}, 
  elem{new T[s]}, 
  space{s}
{
  for (int i=0; i<s; ++i) elem[i]=0;
}

template<typename T> vector<T>::vector(std::initializer_list<T>lst) 
  :sz{int(lst.size())}, elem{new T[sz]} 
{
  std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(),elem);
}

template<typename T> vector<T>::vector(const vector& v) 
  :sz{v.sz}, elem{new T[v.sz]}
{
  std::copy(v.elem, v.elem+sz, elem);
}

template<typename T> vector<T>& vector<T>::operator=(const vector& v) 
{
  if(this == &v) return *this;

  if(v.sz<=space)
  {
    std::copy(v.elem, v.elem+sz, elem); 
    sz = v.sz;
    return *this;
  }

  T* p = new T[v.sz];
  std::copy(v.elem, v.elem+sz, p);
  delete[] elem;
  elem = p;
  space = sz = v.sz;
  return *this;
}

template<typename T> vector<T>::vector(vector&& v)
  :sz{v.sz}, elem{v.elem} 
{
  v.sz = 0;
  v.elem = nullptr;
}

template<typename T> vector<T>& vector<T>::operator=(vector&& v)
{
  delete[] elem;
  elem = v.elem; 
  sz = v.sz;
  v.elem = nullptr;
  v.sz = 0;
  return *this;
}

template<typename T> T& vector<T>::operator[](int n)
{
  return elem[n];
}

template<typename T> const T& vector<T>::operator[](int n) const 
{
  return elem[n];
}

template<typename T> void vector<T>::reserve(int newalloc)
{
  if(newalloc<=space) return;
  T* p = new T[newalloc];
  for(int i=0; i<sz; ++i) p[i] = elem[i];
  delete[] elem;
  elem = p;
  space = newalloc;
}

template<typename T>void vector<T>::resize(int newsize, T def) 
{
  reserve(newsize);
  for(int i=sz; i<newsize; ++i) elem[i] = 0;
  sz = newsize;
}

template<typename T> void vector<T>::push_back(const T& d) 
{
  if(space == 0) {
    reserve(8); 
  } else if(sz==space) { 
    reserve(space*2);
  }
  elem[sz] = d; 
  ++sz;
}
```

Comment: the error does not match the code, there is no `my_struct[]` in your code. Btw `No_default(int) { };` is not using the parameter as a "default value", in fact it just ignores whatever parameter you pass to it

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how to use the int passed as a 'default value'.

Comment: default value for what? I dont know the book, maybe the class has some `int` member and you want to assign the value passed in the constructor to that member?

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and try to provide one. Its not really clear what the problem is, because the code you show seems to be fine and should not result in the error you say

Comment: oh sorry, I missed one important detail: you are not using `std::vector` but something else. The error you get is most likely from the constructor of that vector, but definitely not from the constructor of the `No_default` you show here. It really requires a [mcve] to know what is going on

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I tried reformulating. Will also add the custom vector class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the problem is this line

```
template<typename T> void vector<T>::reserve(int newalloc)
{
    if(newalloc<=space) return;
    T* p = new T[newalloc];
```

`reserve` is called from `resize` and `reserve` tries to default construct `T`.

You should redesign your vector class so that elements that are reserved but not yet part of the vector are not constructed.

You'll need to research *placement new* for this. It lets you separate the allocation of objects from their construction.

Comment: I should make a habit of keep reading a few pages ahead... the problem got solved by using the [std::allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) as a template parameter and rewriting the `reserve`function, using `allocate`, `construct`, `destroy` and `deallocate`.

Comment: OK, that works as well, `construct`just uses placement new so it amounts to the same thing.